# How to save Tensorflow 2 Object Detection Model including all weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am working on Object Detection using Tensorflow 2 API in Python. This works great so far. However, if I want to save the model, I am using `exporter_main_v2.py` which exports a graph (.pb) and a checkpoint (`checkpoint`, `ckpt-0.data`, `ckpt-0.index`). The graph does **not** include any weights, I always have to use the checkpoint to work with the saved model.
Is there any way to save all weights into the Protobuf (.pb) file?

Here's what I've tried:

- Save frozen model: TF2 does obviously not support frozen graphs any more. The `export_inference_graph.py`, which would freeze the graph including all weights, does not work under TF2.
- Same goes with `freeze_graph.py`: Only possible using TF1

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the freezing technique from TF1 in TF2, using the `compat.v1` module:

In the following snippet, I assume that you have a pretrained model with weights saved in the TF2 fashion, with `tf.saved_model.save`.

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
    with sess.as_default():
        # creating the model/loading it from a TF2 pb file
        # (If you have a keras model, you can use 
        #`tf.keras.models.load_model` instead). 
        model = tf.saved_model.load("/path/to/model")

# the default signature might be different.
sign = model.signatures["serving_default"]
# if using keras, just use model.outputs
tensor_out_names = [out.name.split(":")[0] for out in sign.outputs]
    
graphdef = tf.compat.v1.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
    sess, graph.as_graph_def(), tensor_out_names
)
# the following is optional, use only if no more training is required
graphdef = tf.compat.v1.graph_util.remove_training_nodes(graphdef)
tf.python.framework.graph_io.write_graph(graphdef, "./", "/path/to/frozengraph", as_text=False)
```

However, I would refrain to do it other than for compatibility reason with an old tool. The `compat` module might be deprecated one day, and as far as I can understand, there is not a big value having only one file containing the graph+the weights rather than splitting them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I saved the model using `tf.saved_model.save`, however, I am running into this error when executing line 11 of your code snippet: `AttributeError: 'SSDMetaArch' object has no attribute 'signatures'`. By the way: I am trying to combine graph plus weights in one file as I want to convert it to ONNX later, and I have not found a way to do so when there are 2 files (ckpt + graph)...

Comment: You can just use `tf2onnx` with the command `python -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model saved_model_dir --output model.onnx` on a folder containing a tensorfow 2 model.