# Convert a Tensorflow model in SavedModel format (.pb file) saved with tf.saved_model.save to a Keras model (.h5 file)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, export

I'm trying to convert a Tensorflow object detection model that's saved in a SavedModel format (in a folder with `.pb` file, `assets` folder, and `variables` folder) to Keras .h5 for simpler inference. However, trying common StackOverflow answers to this question (e.g.[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59375679/tensorflow-pb-format-to-keras-h5)) results in a `ValueError: Unable to create a Keras model from this SavedModel. This SavedModel was created with tf.saved_model.save, and lacks the Keras metadata.Please save your Keras model by calling model.save or tf.keras.models.save_model.`.

The model was trained and saved using the Tensorflow Object Detection API. Is it still possible to convert it to a Keras model? If so, any suggestions?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65609942/how-to-save-tensorflow-2-object-detection-model-including-all-weights) reference help you to solve this issue?

Comment: have you got the answer? because I'm also finding it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issues while converting `YoloV5` to Tensorflow format to deploy a model. you need to use `keras=True`in the export command of the model. This will generate the `Keras_metadata.pb` file at the directory.
[Please see this link.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/save_model)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to convert the saved_model to h5. Is that possible? I loaded it using tf.keras.models.load_model and when I try to save using tf.keras.models.save_model() I get: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 1071, in get_config
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError